# Basic math on a 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, math

Imagine an american football field displayed on a 2D screen. The field has markers every ten yards. Each marker is just a vertical line spanning the height of the field. Say someone gives you an (x, y) location on the field. **How can you determine the vertical marker that's closest to the (x, y) position without using a loop?**

At the moment I'm using a simple loop like this:

```
// want marker closest to x
float x = randomFloat();

double minDistance = Double.MaxValue;
Marker closestMarker = null;

foreach (Marker m in markers) {
    double d = ABS(x - m.x);
    if (d < minDistance) {
        minDistance = d;
        closestMarker = m;
    }
}
```

I feel like this can be done without checking every marker since the markers are uniformly spaced and we know the total marker count. However I'm drawing a blank when it comes to the necessary division etc.

Comment: You could start from the x,y position and draw an ever expanding circle, stopping on the first intersection with a marker. Either way, you'd need a loop though, but it'd be shorter than checking every single marker. Probably you can use the fact that markers are uniformly spaced... I'll have a think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume that there are `n` markers `x0 ... xn-1` and that `xi = x0 + 10 * i`. Then, the closest one to a point `x` is given by `i = min(n-1, max(0, round((x - x0) / 10)))`.

This is slightly more general than the other answers, since it handles both the case where the first marker is not at `x0 = 0`, as well as the case where `x` is outside the field.

Answer (score 1):

in java:

```
int distanceOfClosestMarker = (int) (Math.floor(givenX / tenYards) * tenYards);
// markersByDistance is map of markers by theirs distance. you can use array instead.
Marker closestMarker = markersByDistance.get(distanceOfClosestMarker);
// array version is this
closestMarker = arrayOfMarkers[distanceOfClosestMarker / tenYards];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just have to round it to the nearest ten, then use divide & multiply by 10 to get the closest marker.

(by the way, if you're using C#, you can just do something similar to

```
var nearestMarker = markers.Min(m => x-m.x);
```

)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assuming that markers is ordered by X coordinate and the first one has X = 0
Marker ClosestMarker(float x, List<Marker> markers) {
    int m = (int)Math.Floor(x / 10);

    if(x - m * 10 < 5) return markers[m];
    else return markers[m + 1];
}
```